# Buffalo Linkstation needs (NasPmService) service installed

Tags: network-attached-storage, buffalo

I have a Buffalo Linkstation (LS-WXL) NAS device installed but it appears to require the NasPmService installed on a server before it works.  Is this normal, do all NAS devices require installation of a service on the server or is this device just different?  It would be good to have a NAS device which is still accessible even when the server is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this specific device, but the whole point of a Network Attached Storage is that you connect it to a network and then access it using network protocols (such as SMB or NFS).

Some devices can have *management tools* that you run from a computer on the network in order to manage them... but the answer to `do all NAS devices require installation of a service on the server` is a definite NO, they are (usually) self-contained and autonomous.